# Probability of achieving equal column vectors from different matrix multiplications.

Tags: probability, matrices, probability-distributions

Say we have some matrices, $X, Y, Z$.

All 3 matrices are $n \times n$, and every entry is $ \{ 0, 1... 4 \}$.

Let $v$ be some $n$-length column vector where every entry is randomly chosen from the same interval $ \{ 0, 1... 4 \}$.

In the case with $XY \neq Z$, say we compute $X(Yv)$, and $Zv$. At each step, every entry, $e$ of the resulting column matrix is replaced with ($e$ modulo 5).

There is (supposedly) at least a $4/5$ chance that $X(Yv) \neq Zv$, but I am having trouble understanding where this (4/5) comes from.

I would think this has to do something with the probability of certain values occuring when performing the dot products in matrix multiplication.

In other words, not all possible $e$ values from $0... n(4^2)$ occur with equal likelihood. I am looking to apply this example to a more general proof- so help with this small example would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: What's fixed and what's random?  Are you saying $X,Y,Z$ are fixed (given), and it is known that $XY\neq Z$, but $v$ is randomly chosen among all $n$-length vectors with each entry uniformly random from $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$?

Comment: @antkam Correct! X/Y/Z are all matrices with entries in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4} and it is known that XY is not equal to Z. $v$ is randomly chosen as you stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $X, Y, Z$ with $XY \neq Z$, we have $A = XY - Z \neq 0$, and let $d =$ the dimension of the null space (kernel) of $A$.  Recall that $v \in nullspace(A)$ iff $Av = 0$ iff $XYv = Zv$.

Since $A \neq 0$, we have $d \le n-1$.  (Only the zero matrix can have a fully $n$-dimensional null space.)

There are $5^n$ choices for $v$, since each of $n$ entries can be $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

There are $5^d$ distinct vectors in the null space of $A$.  (Quick proof: lets say $\{u_1, \dots, u_d\}$ is a basis of the null space of $A$, then every $v$ in the null space is a linear combination $\sum_{i=1}^d a_i u_i$. There are $d$ different $a_i$'s and there are $5$ choices for each $a_i$.)

Therefore, $Prob(v \in nullspace(A)) = 5^d / 5^n \le 5^{n-1} / 5^n = 1/5$ and $Prob(v \notin nullspace(A)) = Prob(XYv \neq Zv) \ge 4/5$